# Word addin stuck in context sync

Tags: ms-word, office-js

when exit from function-file.html 
it come to `word.run` and don't come to `context.sync`
and continue process if I do put to clipboard buffer some text

```js
Word.run(function (context) {

    var originalRange = context.document.getSelection();
    context.load(originalRange, 'parentContentControlOrNullObject, parentTableCellOrNullObject')  
    return context.sync().then(function () {
            var control = originalRange.parentContentControlOrNullObject
```

Comment: Please provide the complete function that calls `Word.run`. You haven't provided enough code for anyone to reproduce. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helped solution

```
Word.run(function (context) {
return new OfficeExtension.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {    
  setTimeout(function(){                
    return context.sync().then(function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

The function that calls `Word.run` must take a parameter and at the end of the function, there should be a line that calls the `completed` method of the parameter.

```
function myFunction(args) {
    Word.run(function (context) {
        // Your code
        return context.sync();
    })
    args.completed();
}
```

For an example, see [Protect a worksheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/excel-tutorial#protect-a-worksheet).